# Easy function gives compile error on conversion from Int to Double

Tags: haskell

Why does this easy function which computes the distance between 2 integer points in the plane not compile?

```
distance :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Double
distance (x, y) (u, v) = sqrt ((x - u) ^ 2 + (y - v) ^ 2)
```

I get the error `Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’`.

It is frustrating such an easy mathematical function consumes so much of my time. Any explanation why this goes wrong and the most elegant way to fix this is appreciated.

This is my solution to overcome the problem

```
distance :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Double
distance (x, y) (u, v) = 
    let xd = fromIntegral x :: Double
        yd = fromIntegral y :: Double
        ud = fromIntegral u :: Double
        vd = fromIntegral v :: Double
    in sqrt ((xd - ud) ^ 2 + (yd - vd) ^ 2)
```

but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: If you remove the type signature or replace it with `distance :: Floating a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a` it will compile just fine. The issue is that sqrt takes a floating a and you've passed it an int, as constrained by your type signature.

Comment: @Zpalmtree But, as an example, why does `sqrt 2` run fine and gives me `1.4142135623730951`?

Comment: @Elmex80s: Because the interpreter looks what the signature of `sqrt` is, and will decode to use a `Float`. In programming languages like Java, if you write `double x = 2;` it will also interpret `2` as a `double`.

Comment: @Elmex80s If you run `:t 2` in ghci, you'll get back `Num p => p`, so 2 is an instance of the Num typeclass. If we run `:info Num` we can see that Double is an instance of Num, and Double is an instance of Floating, so the types unify and 2 becomes a double.

Comment: @Elmex90s To add to this, if you run `sqrt (2 :: Int)` it will fail as expected.

Comment: @Zpalmtree I added my solution, thanks for your help, helped me getting to the solution.

Comment: Basically, Haskell 1) never performs numeric type conversions unless explicitly asked, and 2) considers numeric literals of the type required by the context. So, literals always are of the right numeric type, while variables must be converted explicitly. It can be bothersome, but I now prefer it to implicit conversion which has its own traps, e.g. in Java `1/2*x*x` with double `x` will always evaluate to `0` "thanks" to promotion, while in Haskell does the right™ thing.

Comment: `distance (x, y) (u, v) = sqrt (fromIntegral ((x - u) ^ 2 + (y - v) ^ 2))` is enough. You don't need the explicit `:: Double` type, since you give the explicit type signature to the function `distance`. So, with the explicit top-level type signatures (which are good practice to have, anyway), a few `fromIntegral`s here and there is usually all it takes to take care of it.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, your solution was indeed the elegant solution for me. I already answered it and replied to my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**: now I have this

```
distance :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Double
distance (x, y) (u, v) = sqrt (fromIntegral ((x - u) ^ 2 + (y - v) ^ 2))
```

Answer (score 8):

Most languages only do type inference (if any) “in direction of data flow”. E.g., you start with a value `2` in Java or Python, that'll be an `int`. You calculate something like `2 + 4`, and the `+` operator infers from the integer arguments that the result is also `int`. In dynamic languages this is the only way that's *possible* at all (because the types are only an “associated property” of values). In static languages like C++, the inference-step is only done once at compile time, but it's still done largely “as if the types were associated properties of values”.

Not so in Haskell. Like other [Hindley-Milner languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley-Milner_type_inference), it has a type system that works completely independent of any runtime data flow directions. It can still do forward-inference (`(2::Int) + (4::Int)` is unambiguously of type `Int`), but it's only a special case – types can just as well be inferred in the “reverse direction”, i.e. if you write `(x + y) :: Int` the compiler is able to infer that both `x` and `y` must have type `Int` as well.

This reverse-polymorphism enables many nice tricks – [example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect-0.3.2/docs/Debug-SimpleReflect.html):

```
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect> 2 + 4 :: Expr
2 + 4
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect> 7^3 :: Expr
7 * 7 * 7
```

...but it only works if the language *never does implicit conversions, not even in “safe<sup>†</sup>, obvious cases” like `Int -> Integer`*.

Usually, the type checker automatically infers the most sensible type. For your original implementation, the checker would infer the type

```
distance :: Floating a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
```

and that – or perhaps the specialised version

```
distance :: (Double,Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double
```

is a much more sensible type than your `(Int, Int) -> ...` attempt, because the Euclidean distance makes actually no sense on a discrete grid (you'd want something like a [Taxcab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) there).

What you'd *actually* want is [`distance`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.12/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html#v:distance) from the `vector-space` package. This is more general, works not only on 2-tuples but any suitable space.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>`Int -> Double` is actually *not* a safe conversion – try `float(1000000000000000001)` in Python! So even without Hindley-Milner, this is not really a very smart thing to do implicitly.</sub>